# Cannot build project using xcodebuild, but can using Xcode.app

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcodebuild

I am unable to make a build of my project using the xcodebuild command as it cannot find the singing identity for the development team. However, I can make a build using Xcode.app. This is the error I get with xcodebuild:

```
=== BUILD TARGET AppName OF PROJECT AppName WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "1234567890" with a private key was found.
```

The project settings define that the code signing identify for release builds is set to "iPhone Distribution":

```
"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Distribution";
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 1234567890;
```

And I can see the signing certificate and key in my keychain for that identify:

[image: keychain]

The build command I am using is:

```
xcodebuild \
  -workspace "AppName.xcworkspace" \
  -scheme "AppName (Release)" \
  -destination generic/platform=iOS \
  build
```

The scheme defines to build using release configuration.

Comment: Obviously, the team ID and app name are mocked for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens I was logged in to the build server using SSH and when you log in to a mac using SSH the keychain is not unlocked automatically, therefor even though a certificate did exist, xcodebuild could not access it.

[This question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/270095/when-i-ssh-into-os-x-i-dont-have-my-keychain-when-i-use-terminal-i-do) explains how you can unlock the keychain over ssh, or you can just use Terminal.app locally.